# Is this reasoning correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a finite group of uneven order. Let $x \in G$ be an element with the property that there exist an element $g \in  G$ such that $gxg^{-1} = x^{-1}$. Prove $x$ is the idendity of $G$.

Here is my reasoning, but I think it is incorrect. Why ?
\begin{align*}
x^{-1}=gxg^{-1} &\Rightarrow gx = x^{-1}g \\
&\Rightarrow (gx)^2 = (gx)(x^{-1}g)=g^2 \\ 
&\Rightarrow gx =g \\
&\Rightarrow x =e
\end{align*}

Comment: The step $(gx)^2=g^2$ implies $(gx)=g$ is incorrect.

Comment: @Lepidopterist: Not really. Since $G$ has odd order, the map $x \mapsto x^2$ is bijective $G \rightarrow G$. But that step needs some explanation.

Comment: Sure, but I was asked to point out the incorrect step. You cannot conclude that immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Almost complete! The gap in the proof  is when you go from  from $(gx)^2=g^2$ to $gx=g$. Here you need to use the fact that the group is of **odd order**.

Note that the order of an element must divide the order of the group. So a group of odd order has no elements of order $2$. Use that tool to finish.

**Added:** We need to show that any square has a unique "square root." Consider the object $a^2$. It Since the order of $a^2$ divides the order of the group, $a^2$ has odd order, say $2k+1$. So $a^{2k+1}=e$, and therefore $a^{2k+2}=a$.  So $a=(a^2)^{k+1}$. In particular, $a$ is completely determined by $a^2$.

Comment: I was just thiking that I could take square roots, but this is not true in group theory ? So I need to proof that if $a^2=b^2$ and $a,b$ not of order $2$, then $a=b$. Could you give another hint ? I know that if $a\ne b$ then $a^2 \ne ab$ and $b^2 \ne ab$, but I'm stuck there.

Comment: If $a^2 = b^2$ and $a$, $b$ have odd order, then $a$ and $b$ have the same order. If $a$ has odd order, then $|a| = 2k + 1$ so $a = a^{-2k}$. Or similarly you could just use the fact that $|G| = 2t + 1$.

Comment: @Kasper: Sorry about delay, was away from computer for a few hours. I have added a full completion. It is based on the order is odd idea, and is essentially the same as the comment by m.k..