# Let $x,y$ in a group G with uneven order. Let $x^2=y^2$. Show that $x=y$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $x,y$ in a group G with uneven order. Let $x^2=y^2$. Show that $x=y$.

Okay, how do I prove this? 
If $G$ is unenven order, then there are no elements of order $2$. So $x^2=y^2=e$ only if $x=e$.

But what if the order of $x,y ≥3$ ? Someone told me that I can prove that $x\mapsto x^2$ is a bijection if $x$ has uneven order. How can I see this ?

Comment: In your question 339762, posted some 3 hours ago, you were *specifically* told that what you ask *now* is true whenever the order of the group is odd (=uneven). How come you're asking this now?! Don't you pay minimal attention to the answers you're given?

Comment: @DonAntonio I do pay very wel attention to the answers I'm given, but as I still not understand it after 3 hours of thinking, I'm now asking for a little bit more explanation. Do you have a problem with that ?

Comment: Of course I do: why didn't you ask for clarification in the other question? That way you could have **LEARNED** something and this question you could have answered it at once...! It looks like you're only posing questions, writing down answers and not thinking of them anymore.\

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong about asking this as a separate question. But it would be nice if you add a pointer where the question came up.

Comment: @DonAntonio I would suggest analysing for 3 seconds more before you  judge. If you would have done that, you could see that I have asked for clarification in that question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339762/is-this-reasoning-correct 
But as I still didn't understand that clarification and as I thought that this as an intersting question on his own, I asked it here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of the group $G$ is odd, so it can be written as $2n + 1$ for some $n$.

Since the order of any element divides the order of the group, you have $1 = x^{2n + 1} = y^{2n + 1}$. You also have $x^{2n} = y^{2n}$ since $x^2 = y^2$. Since $x^{2n}x = y^{2n}y$, this means $x$ and $y$ have the same inverse, which in turn means $x = y$. (Or just multiply through by $x^{-2n} = y^{-2n}$).

Comment: Aaah, thank you very much ! But how do you know that $x$ and $y$ must have the same uneven order $2n+1$ ?

Comment: @Kasper This is because the order of an element divides the order of the group.
$x$ and $y$ may not have the same order, but you know that $x^{|G|} = e = y^{|G|}$.

Comment: ooooooh of course thanks :D @rustyracketman

Answer (score 8):

Another hint may be: $$x^1=x^{2m+|G|n}=y^{2m+|G|n}=y^1$$ for some integers $m$ and $n$.

Comment: +1: Nothing wrong in applying Bezout's identity to the coprime integers $2$ and $|G|$ :-)

Comment: Nice one, indeed! +1 ;-)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Since $\left| G\right|$ is odd, 2 is invertible modulo $\left| G\right|$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ \ \color{#C00}{X^J\!=Y^J},\, \ \color{#0A0}{X^K\! = Y^K}\Rightarrow\ X^{(J,K)}\! = Y^{(J,K)},\ $ where $\rm\:(J,K)\:$ denotes $\rm\:gcd(J,K).$

**Proof** $\ $ By Bezout's gcd identity $\rm\ (J,K)\, =\, mJ\!-\!nK\ $ for some $\rm\ m,n\in\Bbb Z.\:$ Therefore

$$\rm X^{(J,K)} = X^{mJ-nK}\! = (\color{#C00}{X^J})^m (\color{#0A0}{X^K})^{-n} = (\color{#C00}{Y^J})^m (\color{#0A0}{Y^K})^{-n} = Y^{mJ-nK}\! = Y^{(J,K)}\quad {\bf QED}$$

**Remark** $\ $ Yours is the special case $\rm\:J = 2^n,\:$ $\rm\,K\,$ odd (= group order), $ $ so the gcd $\rm\:(J,K) = 1.$

**Or,** more conceptually, the set of exponents $\rm\:n\:$ such that $\rm\:X^n\! = Y^n$ are closed under subtraction so closed under gcd, since they form a subgroup/ideal of $\rm\,\Bbb Z,\,$ which is necessarily cyclic/principal, generated by the gcd of all its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a^2=b^2$ and $|G|=2k+1$ then:

$$a=a^{-|G|}a=a^{-2k}=(a^2)^{-k}=(b^2)^{-k}=b^{-2k}=b^{-|G|}b=b$$